# If each thread needs to resume work, whenever any thread finds some new information, how to wait until all threads have finished?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, parallel-processing, lock-free

## A Seemingly Simple Synchronization Problem

### TL;DR

Several threads depend on each other. Whenever one of them finds some new information, all of them need to process that information. How to determine, that all threads are ready?

### Background

I have (almost) parallelized a function `Foo(input)` that solves a problem, which is known to be [P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) and may be thought of as some type of search. Unsurprisingly, so far nobody has managed to successfully exploit parallelism beyond two threads for solving that problem. However, I had a promising idea and managed to fully implement it, except for this seemingly simply problem.

### Details

Information between each of the threads is exchanged implicitly using some kind of shared graph-like database `g` of type `G`, such that the threads have all informations immediately and do not really need to notify each other explicitly. More precisely, each time an information `i` is found by some thread, that thread calls a thread-safe function `g.addInformation(i)` which among other things basically places the information `i` at the end of some array. One aspect of my new implementation is, that threads can use an information `i` during their search even before `i` has been enqueued at the end of the array. Nevertheless, each thread needs to additionally process the information `i` separately after it has been enqueued in that array. Enqueueing `i` may happen after the thread who added `i` has returned from `g.addInformation(i)`. This is because some other thread may take over responsibility to enqueue `i`.

Each thread `s` calls a function `s.ProcessAllInformation()` in order to processes all information in that array in `g` in order. A call to `s.ProcessAllInformation` by some thread is a `noop`, i.e. does nothing, if that thread has already processed all informations or there was no (new) informations.

As soon as a thread finished processing all informations, it should wait for all other threads to finish. And it should resume work if any of the other threads finds some new information `i`. I.e. each time some thread calls `g.addInformation(i)` all threads that had finished processing all previously known informations, need to resume their work and process that (and any other) newly added information.

### My Problem

Any solution I could think does not work and suffers from a variation of the same problem: One thread finished processing all informations and then sees all other threads are ready, too. Hence, this thread leaves. But then another thread notices some new information had been added, resumes work and finds a new information. The new information is then not processed by the thread that has already left.

A solution to this problem may be straight forward, but I can not think of one. Ideally a solution to this problem should not depend on time-consuming operations during a function call to `g.addInformation(i)` whenever a new information is found, because of how many times a second this situation is predicted to appear (1 or 2 Million times per second, see below).

#### Even more background

In my initially sequential application the function `Foo(input)` is called roughly 100k times a second on modern hardware and my application spends 80% to 90% of time executing `Foo(input)`. Actually, all function calls to `Foo(input)` depend on each other, we kind of search for something in a very large space in an iterative manner. Solving a reasonable-sized problem typically takes about one or two hours when using the sequential version of the application.

Each time `Foo(input)` is called between zero and many hundred new informations are found. On average during the execution of my application 1 or 2 million informations are found per second, i.e. we find 10 to 20 new informations on each function call to `Foo(input)`. All of these statistics probably have a very high standard deviation (which i didn't yet measure, though).

Currently I am writing a prototype for the parallel version of `Foo(input)` in go. I prefer answers in go. The sequential application is written in C (actually it's C++, but its written like a program in C). So answers in C or C++ (or pseudo-code) are no problem. I haven't benchmarked my prototype, yet, since wrong code is infinitely slower than slow code.

## Code

This code examples are in order to clarify. Since I haven't solved the problem feel free to consider any changes to the code. (I appreciate unrelated helpful remarks, too.)

### Global situation

We have some type `G` and `Foo()` is a method of `G`. If `g` is an object of type `G` and when `g.Foo(input)` is called, `g` creates some workers `s[1]`, ..., `s[g.numThreads]` that obtain a pointer to `g`, such that these have access to the member variables of `g` and are able to call `g.addInformation(i)` whenever they find a new information. Then for each worker `s[j]` a method `FooInParallel()` is called in parallel.

```golang
type G struct {
  s           []worker
  numThreads  int

  // some data, that the workers need access to
}

func (g *G) initializeWith(input InputType) {
  // Some code...
}

func (g *G) Foo(input InputType) int {
  // Initialize data-structures:
  g.initializeWith(input)

  // Initialize workers:
  g.s := make([]worker, g.numThreads)
  for j := range g.s {
    g.s[j] := newWorker(g) // workers get a pointer to g
  }

  // Note: This wait group doesn't solve the problem. See remark below.
  wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
  wg.Add(g.numThreads)
 
  // Actual computation in parallel:
  for j := 0 ; j < g.numThreads - 1 ; j++ {
    // Start g.numThread - 1 go-routines in parrallel
    go g.s[j].FooInParallel(wg)
  }

  // Last thread is this go-routine, such that we have
  // g.numThread go-routines in total.
  g.s[g.numThread-1].FooInParallel(wg)

  wg.Wait()
}

// This function is thread-safe in so far as several
// workers can concurrently add information.
// 
// The function is optimized for heavy contention; most
// threads can leave almost immediately. One threads 
// cleans up any mess they leave behind (and even in 
// bad cases that is not too much).
func (g *G) addInformation(i infoType) {
  // Step 1: Make information available to all threads.
  // Step 2: Enqueue information at the end of some array.
  // Step 3: Possibly, call g.notifyAll()
}

// If a new information has been added, we must ensure, 
// that every thread, that had finished, resumes work 
// and processes any newly added informations. 
func (g *G) notifyAll() {
   // TODO:
   // This is what I fail to accomplish. I include
   // my most successful attempt in the corresponding.
   // section. It doesn't work, though.
}

// If a thread has finished processing all information
// it must ensure that all threads have finished and
// that no new information have been added since.
func (g *G) allThreadsReady() bool {
   // TODO:
   // This is what I fail to accomplish. I include
   // my most successful attempt in the corresponding.
   // section. It doesn't work, though.
}
```

*Remark:* The only purpose of the wait group is to ensure `Foo(input)` is not called again before the last worker has returned. However, you can completely ignore this.

### Local Situation

Each worker contains a pointer to the global data-structure and searches for either a treasure or new informations until it has processed all information that have been enqueued by this or other threads. If it finds a new information `i` it calls the function `g.addInformation(i)` and continues its search. If it finds a treasure it sends the treasure via a channel it has obtained as an argument and returns. If all threads are ready with processing all information, each of them can send a dummy-treasure to the channel and return. However, determining whether all threads are ready is exactly my problem.

```golang
type worker struct {
  // Each worker contains a pointer to g
  // such that it has access to its member
  // variables and is able to call the
  // function g.addInformation(i) as soon 
  // as it finds some information i.
  g    *G 

  // Also contains some other stuff. 
}

func (s *worker) FooInParallel(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  for {
    a := s.processAllInformation()
    
    // The following is the problem. Feel free to make any 
    // changes to the following block.
    s.notifyAll()
    for !s.needsToResumeWork() {
      if s.allThreadsReady() {
        return
      }
    }

  }
}

func (s *worker) notifyAll() {
  // TODO:
  // This is what I fail to accomplish. I include
  // my most successful attempt in the corresponding.
  // section. It doesn't work, though.

  // An example: 
  // Step 1: Possibly, do something else first.
  // Step 2: Call g.notifyAll()
}

func (s *worker) needsToResumeWork() bool {
  // TODO:
  // This is what I fail to accomplish. I include
  // my most successful attempt in the corresponding.
  // section. It doesn't work, though.
}

func (s *worker) allThreadsReady() bool {
  // TODO:
  // This is what I fail to accomplish. I include
  // my most successful attempt in the corresponding.
  // section. It doesn't work, though.

  // If all threads are ready, return true. 
  // Otherwise, return false.

  // Alternatively, spin as long as no new information
  // has been added, and return false as soon as some
  // new information has been added, or true if no new
  // information has been added and all other threads
  // are ready.
  // 
  // However, this doesn't really matter, because a 
  // function call to processAllInformation is cheap
  // if no new informations are available.
}

// A call to this function is cheap if no new work has
// been added since the last function call.
func (s *worker) processAllInformation() treasureType {
  // Access member variables of g and search
  // for information or treasures. 

  // If a new information i is found, calls the
  // function g.addInformation(i).

  // If all information that have been enqueued to
  // g have been processed by this thread, returns.
}
```

### My best attempt to solve the problem

Well, by now, I am rather tired, so I might need to double-check my solution later. However, even my `correct` attempt doesn't work. So in order to give you an idea of what I have been trying so far (among many other things), I share it immediately.

I tried the following. Each of the workers contains a member variable `needsToResumeWork`, that is atomically set to one whenever a new information has been added. Several times setting this member variable to one does not do harm, it is only important that the thread resumes work after the last information has been added.

In order to reduce work load for a thread calling `g.addInformation(i)` whenever an information `i` is found, instead of notifying all threads individually, the thread that enqueues the information (that is not necessarily the thread that called `g.addInformation(i)`) afterwards sets a member variable `notifyAllFlag` of `g` to one, which indicates that all threads need to be notified about the latest information.

Whenever a thread that has finished processing all information that had been enqueued calls the function `g.notifyAll()`, it checks whether the member variable `notifyAllFlag` is set to one. If so it tries to atomically compare `g.allInformedFlag` with 1 and swap with 0. If it could not write `g.allInformedFlag` it assumes some other thread has taken the responsibility to inform all threads. If this operation is successful, this thread has taken over responsibility to notify all threads and proceeds to do so by setting the member variable `needsToResumeWorkFlag` to one for every thread. Afterwards it atomically sets `g.numThreadsReady` and `g.notifyAllFlag` to zero, and `g.allInformedFlag` to 1.

```golang
type G struct {
  numThreads       int
  numThreadsReady      *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate
  notifyAllFlag        *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate
  allInformedFlag      *uint32 // initialize to 1 somewhere appropriate (1 is not a typo)

  // some data, that the workers need access to
}

// This function is thread-safe in so far as several
// workers can concurrently add information.
// 
// The function is optimized for heavy contention; most
// threads can leave almost immediately. One threads 
// cleans up any mess they leave behind (and even in 
// bad cases that is not too much).
func (g *G) addInformation(i infoType) {
  // Step 1: Make information available to all threads.
  // Step 2: Enqueue information at the end of some array.

  // Since the responsibility to enqueue an information may
  // be passed to another thread, it is important that the
  // last step is executed by the thread which enqueues the 
  // information(s) in order to ensure, that the information
  // successfully has been enqueued.

  // Step 3:
  atomic.StoreUint32(g.notifyAllFlag,1)        // all threads need to be notified
}

// If a new information has been added, we must ensure, 
// that every thread, that had finished, resumes work 
// and processes any newly added informations. 
func (g *G) notifyAll() {
  if atomic.LoadUint32(g.notifyAll) == 1 {
    // Somebody needs to notify all threads.
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(g.allInformedFlag, 1, 0) {
      // This thread has taken over the responsibility to inform
      // all other threads. All threads are hindered to access 
      // their member variable s.needsToResumeWorkFlag
      for j := range g.s {
        atomic.StoreUint32(g.s[j].needsToResumeWorkFlag, 1)
      }
      atomic.StoreUint32(g.notifyAllFlag, 0)
      atomic.StoreUint32(g.numThreadsReady, 0)
      atomic.StoreUint32(g.allInformedFlag, 1)
    } else {
      // Some other thread has taken responsibility to inform
      // all threads. 
  }
}
```

Whenever a thread finishes processing all information that had been enqueued, it checks whether it needs to resume work by atomically comparing its member variable `needsToResumeWorkFlag` with 1 and swapping with 0. However, since one of the threads is responsible to notify all others, it can not do so immediately.

First, it must call the function `g.notifyAll()`, and then it must check, whether the latest thread to call `g.notifyAll()` finished notifying all threads. Hence, after calling `g.notifyAll()` it must spin until `g.allInformed` is one, before it checks whether its member variable `s.needsToResumeWorkFlag` is one and in this case atomically sets it to be zero and resumes work. (I guess here is a mistake, but I also tried several other things here without success.) If `s.needsToResumeWorkFlag` is already zero, it atomically increments `g.numThreadsReady` by one, if it hasn't done so before. (Recall that `g.numThreadsReady` is reset during a function call to `g.notifyAll()`.) then it atomically checks whether `g.numThreadsReady` is equal to `g.numThreads`, in which case it can leave (after sending a dummy-treasure to the channel). otherwise we start all over again until either this thread has been notified (possibly by itself) or all threads are ready.

```golang
type worker struct {
  // Each worker contains a pointer to g
  // such that it has access to its member
  // variables and is able to call the
  // function g.addInformation(i) as soon 
  // as it finds some information i.
  g    *G 

  // If new work has been added, the thread
  // is notified by setting the uint32 
  // at which needsToResumeWorkFlag points to 1.
  needsToResumeWorkFlag *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate

  // Also contains some other stuff. 
}

func (s *worker) FooInParallel(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  for {
    a := s.processAllInformation()

    numReadyIncremented := false
    for !s.needsToResumeWork() {
      if !numReadyIncremented {
        atomic.AddUint32(g.numThreadsReady,1)
        numReadyIncremented = true
      }
      if s.allThreadsReady() {
        return
      }
    }

  }
}

func (s *worker) needsToResumeWork() bool {
  s.notifyAll()
  for {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(g.allInformedFlag) == 1 {
      if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(s.needsToResumeWorkFlag, 1, 0) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}

func (s *worker) notifyAll() {
  g.notifyAll()
}

func (g *G) allThreadsReady() bool {
  if atomic.LoadUint32(g.numThreadsReady) == g.numThreads {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

As mentioned my solution doesn't work.

Comment: *(I appreciate unrelated helpful remarks, too.)* — my recommendation is to go ahead and do your best to reduce this to a minimal example. You clearly put a lot of effort in writing this question, however it might just achieve the opposite result and drive answerers away, provided it doesn't outright attract down- or close votes. By reducing the problem to a minimal example you might also gain additional clarity yourself. Thank you.

Comment: @blackgreen Thank you. I will try to reduce this to a minimal example, but for some days I will leave it like this. I feel like I need to get some distance first.

Comment: Have you considered [sync.Cond](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Cond)? I tried understanding, but there's a lot here and there is interleaving of functional constraints and performance constraints that leave me struggling to form a cohesive picture is my porridge brain. Would be good to maybe list the specific design requirements needed in the solution.

Comment: I've read this twice and it's not clear what you are asking.  Is the question about golang or c?  You mention threads...but no details on how you are launching threads.  Voting to close

Comment: @maxm No, I didn't consider using sync.Cond. Actually, I have never used it so far. I will try and let you know, if I manage.

Comment: @maxm And yes, I understand your difficulties and I will try to edit my question in order to be more precise and clear.

Comment: @Vorsprung Thank you for spending your time reading my question. I understand the difficulties and, as mentioned above, I will edit my question in order to be more precise and clear.

Regarding your questions:
The code I have provided is go. And I clearly stated that I am writing a prototype in go. However, my question is not about go, but rather about that synchronization problem. Threads are launched in `Foo(input)`. To be fair, actually several go-routines are launched and I am aware of the fact that go-routines do not coincide with threads.

Comment: @Vorsprung Due to answers provided in my previous comment, please reconsider voting for closing my question.

Comment: I understand the urge to provide as much information as possible, but I agree with blackgreen that in this case you provide _too_ much information, in particular there are too many details that seem irrelevant to the actual problem. FWIW: I don't think implementing a prototype in go is helpful because go has a very different concurrency model, so there is a good chance that whatever you implement cannot be easily transferred to C++. Instead, try to come up with a simplified minimal example that maintains the important aspects of your actual problem.

Comment: FWIW: if you are using C++20 I think it might be sufficient to use a single std::atomic with wait/notify, but I would need to better understand the problem first.

Comment: @mpoeter Well, providing too much irrelevant information is a mistake, I will hopefully not to repeat. I didn't even expect all of that to be so confusing to be honest, when I was formulating the question. I tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @mpoeter I am aware that a lot of CSP-style message passing in go is not easily transferred to C++. I keep this in mind when writing my prototype. I used these higher level synchronization methods in order to quickly obtain a functioning application in which I can play around with new ideas more easily. In particular, already due to performance I try not to use channels and so on in sections of the code which are critical for performence. Indeed I use very few of them at all, and always it's rather to safe time and be able to concentrate on the important parts of the code.

Comment: I have clarified my question and I am adding a solution I found myself some time later today.

Comment: @blackgreen  In case this is interesting to you: I have carified the question and added a solution myself.

Comment: @maxm In case this is interesting to you: I have carified the question and added a solution myself.

Comment: @Vorsprung In case this is interesting to you:  I have carified the question and added a solution myself.

Comment: @mpoeter In case this is interesting to you: I have carified the question and added a solution myself.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution myself. We exploit, that a call to `s.processAllInformation()` does nothing, if no new information had been added (and is cheap). The trick is to use an atomic variable as a lock to both, for each thread to notify all if necessary and to check whether it has been notified. And then to simply call `s.processAllInformation()` again, if the lock can not be acquired. A thread then uses the notifications to check whether it has to increment the counter of ready threads, instead of to see whether it needs to return work.

**Global situation**

```
type G struct {
  numThreads           int
  numThreadsReady      *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate
  notifyAllFlag        *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate
  allCanGoFlag         *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate
  lock                 *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate

  // some data, that the workers need access to
}

// This function is thread-safe in so far as several
// workers can concurrently add information.
// 
// The function is optimized for heavy contention; most
// threads can leave almost immediately. One threads 
// cleans up any mess they leave behind (and even in 
// bad cases that is not too much).
func (g *G) addInformation(i infoType) {
  // Step 1: Make information available to all threads.
  // Step 2: Enqueue information at the end of some array.

  // Since the responsibility to enqueue an information may
  // be passed to another thread, it is important that the
  // last step is executed by the thread which enqueues the 
  // information(s) in order to ensure, that the information
  // successfully has been enqueued.

  // Step 3:
  atomic.StoreUint32(g.notifyAllFlag,1)        // all threads need to be notified
}

// If a new information has been added, we must ensure, 
// that every thread, that had finished, resumes work 
// and processes any newly added informations. 
//
// This function is not thread-safe. Make sure not to 
// have several threads call this function concurrently
// if these calls are not guarded by some lock.
func (g *G) notifyAll() {
  if atomic.LoadUint32(g.notifyAllFlag,1) {    
    for j := range g.s {
      atomic.StoreUint32(g.s[j].needsToResumeWorkFlag, 1)
    }
    atomic.StoreUint32(g.notifyAllFlag,0)
    atomic.StoreUint32(g.numThreadsReady,0)
}
```

**Local situation**

```
type worker struct {
  // Each worker contains a pointer to g
  // such that it has access to its member
  // variables and is able to call the
  // function g.addInformation(i) as soon 
  // as it finds some information i.
  g    *G 

  // If new work has been added, the thread
  // is notified by setting the uint32 
  // at which needsToResumeWorkFlag points to 1.
  needsToResumeWorkFlag *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate

  incrementedNumReadyFlag *uint32 // initialize to 0 somewhere appropriate

  // Also contains some other stuff. 
}

func (s *worker) FooInParallel(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  for {
    a := s.processAllInformation()

    if atomic.LoadUint32(s.g.allCanGoFlag, 1) {
      return
    }

    if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(g.lock,0,1) { // If possible, lock.
      s.g.notifyAll() // It is essential, that this is also guarded by the lock.

      if atomic.LoadUint32(s.needsToResumeWorkFlag) == 1 {
        atomic.StoreUint32(s.needsToResumeWorkFlag,0)

        // Some new information was found, and this thread can't be sure,
        // whether it already has processed it. Since the counter for
        // how many threads are ready had been reset, we must increment
        // that counter after the next call processAllInformation() in the 
        // following iteration.
        atomic.StoreUint32(s.incrementedNumReadyFlag,0)

      } else {

        // Increment number of ready threads by one, if this thread had not 
        // done this before (since the last newly found information).
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(s.incrementedNumReadyFlag,0,1) {
          atomic.AddUint32(s.g.numThreadsReady,1)
        }

        // If all threads are ready, give them all a signal.
        if atomic.LoadUint32(s.g.numThreadsReady) == s.g.numThreads {
          atomic.StoreUint32(s.g.allCanGo, 1)
        }

      }

      atomic.StoreUint32(g.lock,0) // Unlock.
    }

  }
}
```

Later I may add some order for the threads to access to the lock under heavy contention, but for now that'll do.